# Running kitchen converge with rvm cookbook doesn't work

Tags: rvm, chef-infra, test-kitchen

Trying to run test-kitchen and use the rvm cookbook.
As soon as the node converges with the rvm cookbook I can no longer run `kitchen converge` as it can no longer find the chef-client binary.

```
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:298:in `to_specs': Could not find 'chef' (>= 0) among 13 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
     from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:309:in `to_spec'
     from /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:47:in `gem'
     from /opt/chef/bin/chef-client:22:in `<main>'
>>>>>> Converge failed on instance <default-centos-66>.
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/default-centos-66.log for more details
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
>>>>>> Message: SSH exited (1) for command: [sh -c '
sudo -E /opt/chef/bin/chef-client --local-mode --config /tmp/kitchen/client.rb --log_level auto --force-formatter --no-color --json-attributes /tmp/kitchen/dna.json --chef-zero-port 8889
']
>>>>>> ----------------------
```

Usually on a node we run `rvm use system ; chef-client` to run the chef omnibus binaries.

How can I make it so that I can use the rvm cookbook (https://github.com/martinisoft/chef-rvm) and run `kitchen converge` to repeatedly run converge after making updates to a cookbook I'm working on?

Comment: hey, did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: Not a good one... I just use `kitchen login` and then `rvm reset`.
We would probably need to change how we manage ruby to fix this.